# Optimal exercise for reducing inflammation markers

Tags: exercise, recovery

What type of exercise (HIIT, weight lifting, aerobic) is optimal for reducing proinflammatory cytokines (like TNF-alpha) and increasing anti-inflammatory cytokines (like IL-10)?

C-reactive protein (or CRP, another inflammation marker) levels drop with physical activity, but I'm more interested in cytokines, which are not reflected in CRP levels.

Comment: Not an exercise but a food : Omega-3-6-9

Answer (score 1):

Exercise stimulus is a pro-inflammatory process.

If you do a quick search in scientific litterature you will notice. The best way to reduce inflammation was thought to be cold exposure, but has been widely debunked in recent decades.

The best way to reduce inflammation is probably recovery, and with this I mean every kind of low intensity active recovery type of activity.

This will actually increase blood flow in the district area and reduce inflammation.

If you are referring to whole body inflammatory process, oriental meditative disciplines are claimed to be useful in this sense: but no real proof at all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reduce inflammation, diet and environment are just as important as workouts. Minimal carbs/sugar, tons of vegetables, and cold showers definitely help.

Comment: And, you have evidence of all of this?  Or, is this just your opinion?